# Is it reliable to use Last Modified timestamp of directory while doing a backup?

Tags: c#, windows, backup, ntfs

I'm designing a simple incremental backup tool. Is it possible, that after I modify contents of directory, the "Last Modified" attribute of this directory will stay intact? The reason might be a NTFS glitch or bug, I don't know.

I found out there is an option `NtfsDisableLastAccessUpdate`. Is it also possible to turn off modification timestamp update?

I want to know how reliable this attribute is, so I can decide if it's a good idea to use it to make backups of filesystem.

I'm using `FileSystemInfo.LastWriteTime` to extract that information in C#.

Comment: I know nothing about C#, but I remember reading that some PHP functions don't modify the date modified date unless you explicitly tell them too. From that, I'd gather that your answer depends on how the files were modified.

Comment: Rather than disable the update, it seems that you can only restore a modification-timestamp - see [this discussion](http://superuser.com/questions/710014/how-to-disable-modified-time-stamp-in-windows).

Comment: IIRC, writing a file to `a\b` will only change the modification date of `b` not that of `a`.  So you can't just skip any directories with the same modification date, you still need to iterate through the directory structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not think, the last modified timestamp is reliable.

The timestamp is decided by what *file system* that you are using.

E.g. *FAT32* uses the local timestamp when dealing with modified/created time.

while *NTFS* uses the *UTC* timezone.

Also, *FAT32* has around [2 second resolution for last write times](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724290.aspx).
That means it cannot accurately record the last modified date to seconds.

Also, when you are copying files from FAT32 to NTFS , you see whole bunch of other timestamp [problems](http://ask-leo.com/why_do_file_timestamps_compare_differently_every_time_change.html).

There are rules how timestamp are decided by the [filesystems](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/299648)

Moreover , you could [change the timestamp](http://www.online-tech-tips.com/computer-tips/how-to-change-the-last-modified-date-creation-date-and-last-accessed-date-for-files-and-folders/) of any files and folders using third party tools easily.

Comment: What would be a reliable way of detecting that the file is modified? In case of NTFS.

Answer (score 0):

FSUTIL helps to change timestamp. example command- `fsutil behavior set disablelastaccess 1`

This site may help you to understand parameters. 
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc785435.aspx

Hope this helpful for your designing.

Answer (score 0):

In newer Windows versions, NTFS does not update last modified timestamp on open log files that are actually being written to, until these files are closed or something forces the dates to update (not clear, what it is, but there apparently is some method).

See

https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/asiasupp/2010/12/14/file-date-modified-property-are-not-updating-while-modifying-a-file-without-closing-it/

and

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/2b8baca2-9c1b-4d80-80ed-87a3d6b1336f/file-timestamp-not-updating-on-2008-but-does-on-2003?forum=winservergen&prof=required

No reliably working programmatic workaround has been proposed for batch files. 
Unreliable solution for batch files was calling `dir` on the files that needed their modification dates to be up to date.

On the other hand they mentioned programmatic workaround using Windows API 
**(worked for me)**:

> As the workaround is for any process to open and close a handle to the log files, a tool was written to do exactly that, plus get the file information, using the following APIs:
>   
> CreateFile
>   
> GetFileInformationByHandle
>   
> CloseHandle

I know that for example issuing "Refresh" in "XPlorer2" application somehow does trigger the update so that all applications will start seeing updated "last modified" timestamps.